# Trouble converting PDO query to MySQLi

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have a query that is working fine in PDO but I am needing to convert the query to MySQLi to be compatible with an older server.

Here is the PDO query:

```
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username";
$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$st->execute();

while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
  $db_username = $row['username'];
  $db_password = $row['password'];
}
```

Here is what I have to MySQLi, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $username);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
  $db_username = $obj->username;
  $db_password = $obj->password;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: $username is a variable captured from a login form (not included above)

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=' ".$username.' "";

Comment: @saty NONONO, then you are not parameterizing your query..

Answer (score 1):

Try using the mysqli prepared statement system

```
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );

$query = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=?";
$prep = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$prep->bind_param('s', $username);
$prep->execute();
$result = $prep->get_result(); // Make sure you have mysqlnd installed
if($result) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
         $db_username = $obj->username;
         $db_password = $obj->password;
    }
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

If you don't have mysqlnd installed then the less intuitive way involves [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

```
$prep->execute();
$prep->bind_result($db_username, $db_password);
$prep->fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks @Machavity but I'm having trouble with this. I get a blank screen upon submitting and have tried to turn error reporting on: 

 $status = $prep->execute();
 if ($status === false) {
   die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
 }

Comment: Do you have mysqlnd installed?

Comment: I thought I did but sorry just checked and no I don't :(

Comment: Ok, try the more cumbersome [bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) then

Comment: Brilliant! All working now using bind_result. Thanks for all your help :) Would Vote up if I could...